# Enable S3 server logs from a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to enable S3 server logs for a S3 bucket via a lambda, but it seems that the bucket owner is the only one who can do this (i.e. there's no permission I can request with the lambda role to do this)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketLogging.html

> To set the logging status of a bucket, you must be the bucket owner.

Any way to workaround this to enable my lambda to enable server logs (and their delivery in another bucket) for a S3 bucket?

Comment: As long as the lambda is in the same account as the bucket it is the bucket owner.

Comment: Works for me, make it an answer and I'll accept it